# sql select like junction table

Tags: sql, join

i have one table, which contains that fields

```
mid , email
  1 , 'user_a@...'  
  2 , 'user_b@...' 
  3 , 'user_c@...'
```

and then another table with the following fields / values

```
tid, name  
  1, t_a
  2, t_b 
  3, t_c
```

and other table

```
tid, mid
  1, 1
  1, 2
  1, 3
  2, 2
  2, 3
  3, 1
  3, 2
```

How can i get all users that have 't_a' and 't_b' .. i need to return

```
user_a,
user_c
```

Because user_b does not contains t_a

Comment: i don't have idea of how to start .. yes .. this is homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT e.email
    FROM emails e
        INNER JOIN email_tags et
            ON e.mid = et.mid
        INNER JOIN tags t
            ON et.tid = t.tid
    WHERE t.name IN ('t_a', 't_b')
    GROUP BY e.email
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.name) = 2
```

Comment: But user can contains t_a , t_b , and t_c, i need get users that contains t_a and t_b

Comment: @NullPointerException So the users must have t_a AND t_b but no other t_ values? Is that correct?

Comment: User can contains 1..* t_ , but i need all that contains t_a and t_b

Comment: Added table names, because i don't knowing the correct table names to replace.

Comment: @NullPointerException: Updated my answer with your table names.

Comment: I don't think this works; it returns user_b and user_c where the questions asks for user_a and user_c?